# PXE boot aborted pending request id 21

Tags: pxe, sccm

I am trying to boot from PXE and install Windows via SCCM. Previous computers was OK, but this computer get error: `pending request id 21`

See:

[image]

Cannot get information about this error code.

Answer (score 1):

May not be the answer but I can't comment....yet!

I don't remember the Error/ID number for the following example.

If the pc has been imaged with SCCM before, there is a "switch" thrown within SCCM indicating that.  If that is the case, you'll have to right click the device and select "Clear Required PXE Deployments".  Give SCCM a few minutes to upate itself and try again.  If this doesn't help, I'd have to do some googleing!